# Javascript slideshow error

Tags: javascript, slideshow

So I am trying to make a slideshow of the images I have where you press the start button to start the timer. I believe I have everything coded correctly, but it doesn't change the image ever. I'm not sure what could be wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Slide Show</title>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        var i=0;
        var timeout;
        function preLoadImages()
        {
            if (document.images)
            {
                fire = new Array();
                fire[0] = new Image();
                fire[0] = "./images/fire2.jpg";
                fire[1] = new Image();
                fire[1] = "./images/fire3.jpg"
                fire[2] = new Image();
                fire[2] = "./images/fire4.jpg"
                fire[3] = new Image();
                fire[3] = "./images/fire1.jpg"
            }
            else
            {
                alert("There are no images to preload");
            }
        }
        function startSlideshow()
        {
            if (i < fire.length)
            {
                document.images["fire_pic"].src = fire[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 0;
                document.images["fire_pic"].src = fire[i];
            }
            timeout = setTimeout('startSlideShow()',1000);
        }
        function stopSlideShow()
        {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "preLoadImages()">
    <img name="fire_pic" src="./images/fire1.jpg" height="289" width="432"/>
    <form>
        <br /><br />
        <input type=button value="Start Show" onClick="return startSlideShow();"/>
        <input type=button value="Stop Show" onClick="return stopSlideShow();"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Not getting any errors. The first picture loads like normal, but when I press the Start Show button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have a runtime error** due to inconsistent casing: `startSlideshow` versus `startSlideShow`; choose one. Check your browser console to see the error.

---

Also, your preloader code doesn't work: you're adding `Image` objects to the array, then immediately overwriting them with strings. You should be using:

```
fire = new Array();
fire[0] = new Image();
fire[0].src = "./images/fire2.jpg";
```

Then on `startSlideShow` (or `startSlideshow`)  you should use `document.images["fire_pic"].src = fire[i].src`.

---

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IyEJOlo/1/edit) including all fixes.

Comment: Wow. I looked through all of that thinking there was a spelling error. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks